# Using values from a dataframe to apply a function to a vector

Tags: r, string, lapply, gsub, sapply

I'll start off by admitting that I'm terrible at the `apply` functions, and function writing in general, in R. I am working on a course project to clean and model some text data, and I would like to include a step that cleans up contractions.

The `qdapDictionaries` package includes a `contractions` data frame with two columns, the first column is the contraction and the second is the expanded version. For example:

```
 contraction  expanded
5  aren't     are not
```

I want to use the values in here to run a `gsub` function on my text, which I still have in a large character element. Something like `gsub(contr,expd,text)`.

Here's an example vector that I am using to test things out:

```
vct <- c("I've got a problem","it shouldn't be that hard","I'm having trouble 'cause I'm dumb")
```

I'm stumped on how to loop through the data frame (without actually writing a loop, because it seems like the least efficient way to do it) so I can run all the `gsub`s that I need.

There's probably a simple answer, but here's what I tried: first, I created a function that would return the expanded version if passed a contraction:

```
expand <- function(contr) {
    expd <- contractions[which(contractions[1]==contr),2]
}
```

I can use `sapply` with this and it does work, more or less; looping over the first column in contractions, `sapply(contractions[,1],expand)` returns a named vector of characters with the expanded phrases.

I can't figure out how to combine this vector with `gsub` though. I tried writing a second function `gsub_expand` and changing the expand function to return both the contraction and the expansion:

```
gsub_expand <- function(list, text) {
     text <- gsub(list[[1]],list[[2]],text)
     return(text)
 }
```

When I ran `gsub_expand(sapply(contractions[,1],expand),vct)` it only corrected a portion of my vector.

```
[1] "I've got a problem"   "it shouldn't be that hard"   "I'm having trouble because I'm dumb"
```

The first entry in the contractions data frame is 'cause and because, so the interior `sapply` doesn't seem to actually be looping. I'm stuck in the logic of what I want to pass to what, and what I'm supposed to loop over.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

---

### `stringr::str_replace_all`

The `stringr` package does mostly the same things you can do with base regex functions, but sometimes in a dramatically simpler way. This is one of those times. You can pass `str_replace_all` a named list or character vector, and it will use the names as patterns and the values as replacements, so all you need is

```
library(stringr)
contractions <- c("I've" = 'I have', "shouldn't" = 'should not', "I'm" = 'I am')
str_replace_all(vct, contractions)
```

and you get

```
[1] "I have got a problem"                 "it should not be that hard"          
[3] "I am having trouble 'cause I am dumb"
```

No muss, no fuss, just works.

---

### `lapply`/`mapply`/`Map` and `gsub`

You can, of course, use `lapply` or a `for` loop to repeat `gsub`. You can formulate this call in a few ways, depending on how your data is stored, and how you want to get it out. Let's first make a copy of `vct`, because we're going to overwrite it:

```
vct2 <- vct
```

Now we can use any of these three:

```
lapply(1:length(contractions), 
       function(x){vct2 <<- gsub(names(contractions[x]), contractions[x], vct2)})

# `mapply` is a multivariate version of `sapply`
mapply(function(x, y){vct2 <<- gsub(x, y, vct2)}, names(contractions), contractions)

# `Map` is a multivariate version of `lapply`
Map(function(x, y){vct2 <<- gsub(x, y, vct2)}, names(contractions), contractions)
```

each of which will return slightly different useless data, but will also save the changes to `vct2`, which now looks the same as the results of `str_replace_all` above.

These are a little complicated, mostly because you need to save the internal version of `vct` as you go with each change made. The `vct <<-` writes to the initialized `vct2` *outside* the function's environment, allowing us to capture the successive changes. Be a little careful with `<<-`; it's powerful. See `?assignOps` for more info.

Comment: The stringr function did it for me after a quick conversion of the contractions data frame into a named character vector. Thanks for the recommendation. One thing I noticed is that the `str_replace_all` function doesn't seem to have an `ignore.case` argument; I was able to add `tolower` in front of the string in the call for the function to do what I wanted, though.

I'll have to do some more homework on the latter options you suggested, but at least it wasn't something too obvious that I was just missing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad it's useful! A little trick for doing case-insensitive regex: If you prepend your pattern with `(?i)`, it sets a case-**i**nsensitive flag for what follows, so `grepl('(?i)hello', 'Hello, world!')` returns `TRUE`. In the above case, you can paste it in front of the names of `contractions`, and it will _search_ case insensitively. It still won't _replace_ with the same capitalization, though; I don't have a magic bullet for that.

Comment: That is another helpful tip. I intended to modify my text into all lowercase anyway, so whether I do it here in the contractions replacement or use yours and end up with some incorrect case replacements and then do `tolower` later, it should be the same either way. Thanks again.